# Unequal batteries in parallel (theory only & assuming ideal voltage sources)

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, electrical-resistance, voltage

I know that for identical batteries in parallel, the total voltage remains unchanged. However, what would happen if you connect batteries of different voltages in parallel?

As an example, could someone walk me through how you would find the potential at points A, B, C, D & E in the following diagram:[image]

Comment: This is impossible ‘in theory’, you get equations like $0=1$. In reality you need to account for the inherent resistances of the batteries.

Comment: I agree with hdhondt. One can place two voltage sources in parallel, but unless the voltages have internal resistance (which all physical batteries must), then the current flowing through the battery with the smaller voltage would be infinite by Kirchoff's voltage rule. In reality, you must add some resistance in series to simulate the internal resistance of a battery.

Comment: Makes no sense.  Points A, B, C, D and E are the same point.

Answer (score 2):

Your batteries are not "in parallel". Each has a resistor in series with it (R2 and R4). Also, all 5 points A,B,C,D, E are at the same potential because they are connected to each other (as well as to the negative poles of the batteries) with short circuits.

If you consider the negative pole of a battery to be at 0 V then the voltage at points A,B,C,D and E is also 0 V.

Note that the potential at a point is always a relative measure: it is always measured with reference to another point. As your circuit is "floating" (not connected to ground), you can assume *any* point of your circuit to be the reference point from which other voltages are measured. Because of that, the voltage at your points A,B,C,D,E can be any value you like - as long as you pick a suitable reference point. However, the negative pole of the batteries is the most logical point; hence your values are all 0 V.

Below I have redrawn your circuit to illustrate my points, assuming the negative pole of the battery is ground.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

unequal voltage sources in parallel represent an ill-posed question for which no solution exists. In practice, the greater of the two voltage batteries will force current through the other battery in the "backwards" direction.